# htaccess rewrite regex for pagination urls

Tags: .htaccess

I need an expression that would rewrite (actually 301 redirect) old url patterns ended with -0.htm, to new ones -1.htm

so if old url was `/path/to/pagination/script-0.htm` 
new url must be `/path/to/pagination/script-1.htm` 
This must work for any number of folder/subfolder structure.
And must work only for [`-0.htm`]. Only for urls that end with this pattern.

Any idea on how to accomplsh this?
My htaccess regex knowledge is limited to none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\-0\.htm$ $1-1.htm [R=301,L]
```

But make sure it's one of the first rules, before the ones that might do a pass-through if a real file.